# Finding the components of local Minkowski basis vectors in terms of the Schwarzchild coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

If I am an observer in a system with Schwarzchild geometry, I can construct a set of local basis vectors such that $\textbf{e}_{\alpha}\cdot\textbf{e}_{\beta} = \eta_{\alpha \beta}$ that are valid in my local region. How would I go about expressing the components of these basis vectors in terms of the global coordinates $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$? So what I'm wondering is how to calculate $(\textbf{e}_{\alpha})^{\mu}$ for the $\mu^{th}$ component of my basis vector.

In my lectures he quotes these formula without proof and I can't figure out how to derive them from the metric.

Comment: Do you mean [Fermi coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_coordinates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not totally sure I am understanding you well, but the usual Schwarzschild metric is
$$ ds^2=-\left(1-\frac{2GM}{r}\right)dt^2+\left(1-\frac{2GM}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2+r^2(d\vartheta^2+\sin^2\vartheta d\varphi^2), $$ which means the matrix of the metric components is diagonal:

$$ (g_{\mu\nu})=\text{diag}\left(1-\frac{2GM}{r},\left(1-\frac{2GM}{r}\right)^{-1},r^2,r^2\sin^2\vartheta\right). $$

Diagonality of the metric components mean that the coordinate system is orthogonal, so all coordinate bases are orthogonal. You can obtain an ortho**normal** frame then by dividing with the square root of the metric components because $g_{\mu\nu}=g(\partial_\mu,\partial_\nu)$ (where $\partial_\mu$ is the $\mu$-th coordinate basis vector), so the **square** of $\partial_\mu$'s length is $g(\partial_\mu,\partial_\mu)=g_{\mu\mu}$ (no sum implied), therefore $\mathbf{e}_\mu=\partial_\mu/\sqrt{|g_{\mu\mu}|}$.

What are the components of $\partial_\mu$? For any basis, the components of the $\mu$-th basis vector **in that basis** is given by $(0,0,...,1,...0)$ where the 1 is in the $\mu$-th spot, so $(\partial_\mu)^\nu=\delta_\mu^\nu$ (in this coordinate system only), therefore $$ (\mathbf{e}_\alpha)^\mu=\frac{\delta_\alpha^\mu}{\sqrt{|g_{\alpha\alpha}|}}=\text{diag}\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{r}}^{-1},\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{r}},\frac{1}{r},\frac{1}{r\sin\vartheta}\right). $$

---

Edit: If you are unfamiliar with invariant notation, consider that if $e^\mu_\alpha$ is the $\mu$th component of the $\alpha$th basis vector, then $e^\alpha_\mu$ is the inverse matrix of $e^\mu_\alpha$ (this inverse matrix is actually the *dual frame*).

The inverse matrices satisfy $$ g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\alpha\beta}e^\alpha_\mu e^\beta_\nu$$, so

$$ ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu=\eta_{\alpha\beta}e^\alpha_\mu e^\beta_\nu dx^\mu dx^\nu=\eta_{\alpha\beta}e^\alpha e^\beta, $$ where $e^\alpha=e^\alpha_\mu dx^\mu$, so for Schwarzschild specifically
$$ ds^2=-a(r)dt^2+a(r)^{-1} dr^2+r^2 d\vartheta^2+r^2\sin^2\vartheta d\varphi^2=-e^0e^0+e^1e^1+e^2e^2+e^3e^3, $$ from which you can read off $e^0=\sqrt{a(r)}dt$, $e^1=\sqrt{a(r)^{-1}}dr$, $e^2=rd\vartheta$ and $e^3=r\sin\vartheta d\varphi$ and since each of these expression contain only one differential, $e^0_0=\sqrt{a(r)}$ while $e^0_{\text{any other index}}=0$ etc., so
$$ e^\alpha_\mu=\text{diag}\left(\sqrt{a(r)},\sqrt{a(r)^{-1}},r,r\sin\vartheta\right), $$
but what you are looking for, $e^\mu_\alpha$ is the inverse of this matrix, which gives the same result I gave before the edit (with $a(r)=1-\frac{2GM}{r}$ obviously).