# Decomposing velocities in the tetrad frame

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

### **Background**

At each point in a manifold we can find an orthonormal set of basis vectors  $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_\alpha$ such that
$$
g(\mathbf{e}_\hat{\alpha}, \mathbf{e}_\hat{\beta}) = \eta_{\alpha \beta}
$$

This set of vectors compromising an orthonormal basis is referred to as a tetrad (S. Carroll, An Introduction to General Relativity p.483).

In places such as [Javier's answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/495390/246795), page 5 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4430) and page 7 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.5058), the authors seem to decompose the 4-velocity on the tetrad frame as

$$
\mathbf{u} = \gamma(v) (\mathbf{e}_\hat{0} + v^{\hat{i}} \mathbf{e}_\hat{i})
$$

### **Questions**

Why is this decomposition possible? To me, this looks like we are using the special relativistic 4-velocity formula which suggests that the tetrad frame is a flat local inertial frame (Minkowski). **So, does tetrad frame = local Minkowski frame?** Further, [Javier](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/495390/246795) mentions that the special relativistic decomposition works in all orthogonal reference frames - is this true?

### **Contextual example**

Take the case of FRW universe with the FRW metric
$$
ds^2 = dt^2 - R(t)^2[d\chi^2 + S^2(\chi)(d\theta^2+\sin^2(\theta)d\phi^2)]
$$

For a test particle moving with velocity $v$ relative to comoving cosmological observers at cosmic time $t$, show that as mesaured by the comoving observers:
$$
\gamma(v)v \propto \frac{1}{R(t)}
$$

(We may assume that we can take $R(t)^2 \dot{\chi} = \text{const.}$ as a given as it is not immediately relevant to the topic of the question, though it can be found from the constraint of geodesic motion for the particle).

#### **Solution?**

- Take the test particle to be of unit mass, hence in the coordinate frame its 4-velocitty is $u^{\mu} = (\dot{t}, \dot{\chi}, 0,0)$ (we can assume radial motion W.L.O.G by the symmetry of FRW geometry).
- As a vector this 4-velocity is $\mathbf{u} = \dot{t} \mathbf{e}_\hat{t} + \dot{\chi}\mathbf{e}_\hat{\chi}$.
- The comoving observers will observe quantities according to their tetrad frame $\mathbf{e}_\hat{\alpha}$ which is related to the old coordinate frame by a vielbein $\mathbf{e}_\hat{\alpha} = e^{\mu}_{\; \alpha} \mathbf{e}_\hat{\mu}$ such that $g_{\mu \nu} = e_{\mu}^{\; \alpha} e_{\nu}^{\; \beta} \eta_{\alpha \beta}$. We find that for the FRW metric

$$
e^{\mu}_{\; \alpha} = \mathrm{diag}[1, R(t), R(t)S(\chi), R(t)S(\chi)\sin(\theta)]
$$

- Therefore, we can relate our tetrad frame (${\mathbf{e}_\hat{0}, \mathbf{e}_\hat{1}, \mathbf{e}_\hat{2}, \mathbf{e}_\hat{3}}$) to the coordinate frame by
  $$
  \mathbf{e}_\hat{t} = \mathbf{e}_\hat{0}, \;
  \frac{1}{R(t)}\mathbf{e}_\hat{\chi} = \mathbf{e}_\hat{1}, \;\text{...}
  $$
- Now **if we assume the decomposition above is correct** then $
  \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{e}_\hat{1} = \gamma(v) v$. (I.e. we are projecting onto the comoving observers frame to take the measurement.) But $\frac{1}{R(t)}\mathbf{e}_\hat{\chi} = \mathbf{e}_\hat{1}$ and $
  \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{e}_\hat{\chi} = g(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{e}_\hat{\chi}) = g_{\chi \chi}\dot{\chi} = -R(t)^2\dot{\chi}$
- Hence, compiling results (and remembering $R(t)^2 \dot{\chi} = \text{const.}$) we get the result.

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/495383/246795 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/747346/246795

Comment: Also related  and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3050273/868580 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/306465/246795